# Moving files without overwrite

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, filesystems

I'm using the following command to move all files in subfolders to a destination folder, without overwriting files with same name:

```
find folder-target -type f -exec cp --backup=numbered \{\} folder-final \;
```

And this is causing the files append ~1~ if the file already exists. The problem is: this is causing the file usuless. I need catch all my pdfs, and i can't open this pdfs if they have this numbers.

Is this fixable? Can't i use a pre-fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try cp -n

see man pages here : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html

Comment: If i use -n i won't catch all files Sanya :B